# Array image looping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to loop traffic light images in JavaScript. I'm not sure what to do, can someone give advice.

Comment: if(!div.count || dvi.count == image.length ) , spelling mistake here. you have mixed up div and dvi..

Comment: I see a `div.count` in there. I'm assuming its supposed to be `dvi`? Also you need to provide a valid function to `setTimeout` not a string.

Comment: @apokryfos `setTimeout` can take a string as its first argument - it `eval`s it. Bad practice, but it works nonetheless

Comment: and you are setting div.count = 0 within the function and then doing +1 on it.. so everytime changeimage get's called through timeout, div.count becomes 0 and that will result in you seeing the same image every time..

Comment: @Ankit - I think you're missing the `if` above it. Albeit badly indented, having a typeo, and missing the optional braces, that line `div.count=0` is called only if the count doesnt exist, or if the count equals the length (to cycle back round I assume)

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to your code. Here is a working sample.

I removed the `dvi.count` counter as it creates more confusion, We need to maintain the counters outside the function. I changed the logic to pass around the index of the image in the array starting from 0.

```js
var image = new Array("red.jpg", "redamber.jpg", "green.jpg", "amber.jpg");
var timeout;

function stopIt() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}

function changeimage (images, index) {
  var dvi = document.getElementById(images);
  
  if(image.length <= index)
     index = 0;

  dvi.src = image[index];
  dvi.alt = image[index];

  timeout = setTimeout('changeimage("' + images + '",' + (index + 1) + ')', 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="changeimage('changer',0)">
  <div>
    <img src="t1" alt="test1" id="changer" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have made 3 changes to your code

1. Fixed the typeo `div.count` to `dvi.count`
2. Corrected the indenting and braces round the `if` statement (Not strictly necessary, but makes the code way more readable)
3. Replaced your nasty use of a string parameter in `setTimeout` to be a function reference

---

```
function changeimage(images){
    var dvi=document.getElementById(images);
    if(!dvi.count || dvi.count == image.length ){
        dvi.count=0;
    }
    dvi.src=image[dvi.count];
    dvi.alt=image[dvi.count];
    dvi.count=dvi.count+1;
    timeout=setTimeout(function(){
        changeimage(images);
    },3500);
}
```

---

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lofug2hf/1/